# Kibana reverse proxy with Active Directory Authentication

Tags: nginx, kibana-4

I would like to restrict access to Kibana (deployed on a Windows Server) by an Active directory group, I understand I need to setup a reverse proxy.
I wanted to know what are different reverse proxy solutions that support active directory based authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use shield for that instead of a RP. https://www.elastic.co/products/shield